# How to get year numbers in columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to display the number of transactions in individual years for individual employees (ID, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014) and I should see the number of transactions in every year under years number, but now I receive this form:

[image: current form]

How can I change it?

I think I should use WHERE, but I dont know how to do it

My current query is:

```
SELECT oh.SalesPersonID AS perID, 
       YEAR(oh.OrderDate) AS [Year], COUNT(*)
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader oh 
JOIN Person.Person per ON oh.SalesPersonID = per.BusinessEntityID 
GROUP BY SalesPersonID, YEAR(OrderDate)
ORDER BY perID, [Year];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT oh.SalesPersonID AS perID, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(oh.OrderDate) = 2011 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as cnt_2011,
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(oh.OrderDate) = 2012 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as cnt_2012,
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(oh.OrderDate) = 2013 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as cnt_2013,
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(oh.OrderDate) = 2014 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as cnt_2014
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader oh JOIN
     Person.Person per
     ON oh.SalesPersonID = per.BusinessEntityID 
GROUP BY SalesPersonID
ORDER BY perID;
```

Comment: Nice answer. An alternative might be to use a pivot query, but I like this solution's simplicity.